# How to redirect URL in Go main method?

Tags: go, http-redirect

I have a GorrilaMux set up in Go that will make an API call if type in a specific URL in a browser. I want to make the same API call in my main method in go if the URL is given as a command line argument. However, the http.redirect() method which seems to be able to do this, requires a HTTP ResponseWriter and a *HTTPRequest variables as function parameters. I do not know how to produce these variables within a main method. How do I do this, OR, is there a better way to make the API call from the URL in Golang?

Code to set up Router

```
func main(){
   router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
   for _, route := range routes { //Sets up predefined routes
     router.
        Path(route.Path).
        Name(route.Name).
        Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

  URL:="localhost:8080/whatever" //URL I want to redirect, route would be "/whatever"

 http.redirect(????)

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

An HTTP redirect is a response to a client and should be called from an invocation of a handler. The `http.redirect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` function has no meaning in the context of the main function.

You can register a handler for the given route like so:

```
router.Path("/whatever").Handler(func(writer http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(writer, req, "localhost:8080/whatever", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
))
```

This adds a path to the router and invokes the simple `http.Handlerfunc` which contains a call to `http.Redirect(...)`. Here this makes sense because we are handling a response to a client connection. It is logical to return a 301 status code and the URL for the target of the redirect.

Comment: No no, I know how to set up a Handler. What I want to do is that instead of opening up my browser and typing in the URL to trigger the API call via the router, I want to trigger the API call with a URL, via command line argument, within the program. 

So if I were to type in command line:

 go run *.go -url="localhost:8080/Whatever"

The go program's main method would parse the URL and send it to the router. I'm basically trying to figure out how to send the URL to the Mux Router within the main method

Answer (score 0):

We use a helper function to make the code cleaner.

```golang
// Redirect will peform an HTTP redirect to the given redirect Path.
func Redirect(redirectPath string) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Redirect(w, r, redirectPath, http.StatusFound)
    }
}


router.Path("/whatever").Handler(Redirect("/test_path"))
router.Path("/whatever2").Handler(Redirect("/test_path2"))
```