# How to call/open a URL within Go method?

Tags: go, url-routing, gorilla, mux

I have a Gorilla Mux router set up in Go. I have routes set up within that router, as well as function handlers associated with those routes. The router works perfectly, **if** you open a browser window and enter specific URLs. However, the problem I'm running into is what to do if the URL is entered on the command line. I know how to store the URL from the command line arguments, but I don't know how to forward the URL, stored as a URL variable in Go, to the router. Like, how do you call a route's function handler if the URL is given on the command line INSTEAD of entered via browser window?

Code:

```
u, err := url.Parse(os.Args[1])
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

host, port, _ := net.SplitHostPort(u.Host)

s := []string{":", port};

router := ANewRouter()

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(strings.Join(s, ""), router))

//Route URL to router, somehow
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use something like `curl` to make a request from the command line?

Comment: @JimB No, definitely not that. This question tends to be pretty confusing to ask. It's more like, the url is given on the command line like so "go run *.go -url="http://localhost:8080/something" where the go application parses the URL flag for the URL

Comment: Posting the code you have would help

Comment: When you enter the URL into the command line, what is the problem you're running into? Does the program throw an error? Posting that would help.

Comment: Are you trying to serve from the url the user entered? Because that's what you're code is doing. If you're trying to make a request to it, my answer should have you covered.

Comment: I'm not sure what "serving", I apologize I'm really new to this. Basically, I want to make an API call from a specific URL. I can do this by entering the URL in a browser window, I want to do the same thing via a GO method and a given URL without opening a broswer window

Comment: is this the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293072/how-to-redirect-url-in-go-main-method

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make an HTTP request in Go there are easy to use methods for that purpose in the standard library at; https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

As JimB pointed out in comment you could use something like `curl` and just forgo using Go altogether. Launching `curl` from Go doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me when you can just do `resp, err := http.Get(urlArg)` and get the same result. There are also methods for other HTTP verbs and if you need more fine tuned control of the request you can use the `Do` method and create `Request` object to do things like set headers.

Comment: That didn't work. I did:

http.Get("http://localhost:8080/list") 

And nothing happened. I entered "http://localhost:8080/list" into a browser, and it made the API call

Comment: @AbhishekSaha make sure you use `http://localhost:8080/list` for your request in Go. Then check the value of `err` and `resp`. If `err` is not nil you got a 200 and can proceed to read the response body. Try printing it to console for debugging. I guarantee that method will do what you want if you use it right.

Comment: If I try the http.Get call after I start the router, it doesn't get called. If I try the http.Get call before I start the router, I get this error: "getsockopt: connection refused". 

I start the router like so: "log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))"

Comment: @AbhishekSaha this code should not be in your API... They should be two different applications. Start your API, write this code as it's own little stand alone main and run it from the command line. Your API calling itself based on arguments passed in from the command line by a user makes no sense at all...

Comment: That worked, thanks for the help man. Trust me, I would not be using Go if I didn't have to

Comment: @AbhishekSaha np. Try to keep a positive outlook. Go is a great language and these concepts carry over to others. If you wanted to do the same in C# the code required would be nearly the same, even down to the methods, class and package names.